# Integrate $\int_{0}^{\pi}{-\cos{x}}{_2F_1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos{^{2}x}\right)\sin{^{1+n}x}\sin{^{2}x}^{\frac{-1-n}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

May I expect the closed-form of this integral?

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi}{{_2F_1}\left(\left.\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{-n+1}{2}\\&\frac{3}{2}\end{array}\right|\cos^2(x)\right)(-\cos{x})(\sin{^{n+1}x})(\sin{^{2}x})^{\frac{1}{2}(-n-1)}\,dx}$$

or at least

> $$\int{{_2F_1}\left(\left.\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{-n+1}{2}\\&\frac{3}{2}\end{array}\right|\cos^2(x)\right)(-\cos{x})(\sin{^{n+1}x})(\sin{^{2}x})^{\frac{1}{2}(-n-1)}\,dx}$$

The integrand is a result of
$$\int{\sin{^{n}(x)}\,dx}.$$

I'm hoping that someone could do the closed-form because my *Mathematica* couldn't make the result even I tried to put $n=2$ and $n=3$.

Thank you.

Comment: is there any reason to expect a closed form solution?

Comment: http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/21/01/02/02/ maybe that leads to something

Comment: by the way, the sine-terms cancel ,right ?

Comment: @tired It's possible but integrate hypergeometric function with the sines and the cosines is rare here.

Comment: the point is: as written above the sine terms cancel to $1$. Afterwards u can straightforwardly apply $y=cos(x) $ followed by $y=\sqrt{q}$. the resulting integral seems to be solvable by one of the identities in the link given above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *May I expect the closed-form of this integral ?*

Yes, you may. In fact, the answer is $0$, due to the [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) of the sine and cosine functions.

---

> *my Mathematica couldn't make the result even when I tried to put $n=2$ and $n=3$.*

*Mathematica* has no problem evaluating the integral, even in its hypergeometric form, once the two sine terms have been reduced.

---

> *The integrand is a result of* $\displaystyle\int\sin^n(x)~dx.$

If you are already familiar with *Mathematica*, then you should probably know that it contains a very useful command called `FunctionExpand[...]` . Applying it to the original integrand yields $\pm~\dfrac12~B\bigg(\cos^2x~,~\dfrac12~,~\dfrac{n+1}2\bigg),~$ where the sign is opposite to that of the cosine function. Again, notice the parity of the integrand. Also, $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sin^n(x)~dx$ is a [Wallis integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals), whose relation to the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) is well-known.

Comment: **Note:** The parity I speak of is taken with regard to $\dfrac\pi2,$ and not with regard to $0,$ since $\cos\bigg(\dfrac\pi2+x\bigg)=-\cos\bigg(\dfrac\pi2-x\bigg).$

Comment: I don't get what do you do with "FunctionExpand[...]" to prevent the parity of the integrand. I mean how the code in Mathematica will be.

Comment: @user294110: What do you mean by *prevent* ?

Comment: You wrote "*notice the parity of the integrand*" so what code I need to input for the "FunctionExpand[...]"?

Comment: @user294110: Your hypergeometric integrand and/or the integral of $\sin^nx$

Comment: I put $n=2$ and the result is 0 by `Integrate[(Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -(1/2), 3/
    2, (Cos[x])^2]) (-(Cos[x])) ((Sin[x])^3) (((Sin[x])^2)^(-3/2)), {x, 0, \[Pi]}]` but if I drop the $(-\cos{x})$, the result would be beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: @user294110: Beautiful, but irrelevant, since you're evaluating a different integral. I told you to drop the **sine** terms, since they cancel each other out anyway.